# how to know the memory size utilized while running an application with valgrind?

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I am working on valgrind and I want to know the size of memory utilized (RAM + memory cache) while I run my code. I know that valgrind can give me the memory detection and run time, but I focus on memory size utilized. How can i get this size with valgrind? or there is an other tool can do this? can someone help me please. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [massif heap profiler](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) for this:

```
valgrind --tool=massif yourtool --verbose
```

The result will then be in a file `massif.out.pid`, and can be visualised via `ms_print`.